# How do I reset input autocomplete styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple Bootstrap form that is proceeded via JavaScript. Once the submit button is clicked, it proceeds its data and resets the input values without reloading the page:

```
if( json.success ) {
  $('#form_sendemail').find('.form-control').val('');
}
```

The problem is that if there were any autocompleted form fields (highlighted with yellow in Chrome), they stay highlighted even after the form has been sent and the form fields cleared. How do I reset those styles without reloading the page? (setting `background-color` to `!important` didn't help).

[image]

Comment: I think you should try to reset your form with .reset(), once your form is submitted successfully.

Comment: @Nimmi, this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out the [reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) function:

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    success: function (data, status) {
        document.getElementById('yourFormID').reset();
    }
});

<form id="yourFormID"></form>
```

**EDIT:**

JQuery (the awesome):

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    success: function (data, status) {
        $('#yourFormID')[0].reset();
    }
});
```

Comment: Since you using JQuery, `$('#yourFormID')[0].reset();`

Comment: $('#yourFormID')[0].reset(); actually worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, I have edited answer for future questions

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**For Chrome**

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #FAFFBD !important;
color: #2a2a2a !important;
}
```

**Script**

```
$("input[type='text']").bind('focus', function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
   $(this).css('color', '#000');
});
```